participants or the participants
I'm relatively new to academia and I've noticed scientists write "participants" instead of "the participants" in the context of, for example, "participants did this" in the methods section of journal articles. In my opinion, it should be "the participants", since the particular participants that researchers recruited do an experiment.
Why do scientists write "participants" instead of "the participants"? Thanks in advance.

Writing "participants did this" is too little to go on. You should include real life examples of sentences, where possible with links to the sources.

I've cast my vote to close the question because it lacks detail, someone else voted that this question should be migrated to ELL. One more vote in favor of closure and it will be closed.

Maybe not all the participants did this? Not enough to go on.
